# Add labels to a mosaic plot in R

Tags: r, plot, mosaic-plot

I have the following table `x` which looks like this:

```
> x <- table(married_working_women$fem_ed, married_working_women$hom_ed)
> rownames(x) <- c("< HS", "HS", "> HS")
> colnames(x) <- c("< HS", "HS", "> HS")
> x
      
       < HS   HS > HS
  < HS 2410  112  283
  HS     63   83   55
  > HS   44   49  172
```

I create the Mosaic plot using the following code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

mosaicplot(x,
           main = "Education Levels of Working Spouses",
           xlab = "Wife's Education",
           ylab = "Husband's Education",
           las = 1, color = brewer.pal(3, name = "Pastel2"))
```

which gives this result:

[image]

Now I want to add the numbers in the table `x`, and maybe also the percentages, to the mosaic plot. Here is an example:

[image]

I tried to use `mosaic` function, but it gives an error:

```
> library(vcd)
> mosaic(x, labeling = labeling_cells(text = round(x, 2)), legend = TRUE)
Error in `[.default`(c(2410, 63, 44, 112, 83, 49, 283, 55, 172), `NA` = NA_character_,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Can someone please give me a hint as to how to add labels to the `mosaicplot` function? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but the key was to never use `colnames(x)` and `rownames(x)`. You should use `dimnames(x)` instead when creating your table. Code was based on this [RStudio post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/visualise-2x2-table-in-ggplot-with-mosaic-plot/55715) and this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516504/mosaic-function-of-the-vcd-package-error-in-adding-text-in-the-cells).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(vcd)

x <- read_delim("
2410 112 283
63 83 55
44 49 172", col_names = FALSE)
x <- as.table(as.matrix(x))

dimnames(x) <- list(A = c("< HS", "HS", "> HS"),
                    B = c("< HS", "HS", "> HS")) 
percentages <- round(100*prop.table(x), 3)
txt <- as.table(matrix(paste0(x, "; ", percentages, "%"), 3, 3))
dimnames(txt) <- dimnames(x)

vcd::mosaic(x, pop = F, shade = T, colorize = T, 
            gp = gpar(fill = matrix(c("grey", "green", "red", "blue", "yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "grey"),  3, 3)))

labeling_cells(text = txt, margin = 0)(x)
```

[image]